# SVN Checkout: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: svn, file-exists

I'm trying to checkout an SVN repository (that I have used for over 4 years on other computers) on a new laptop (windows 8.1) to work on a project. I keep running into an error message at the same point during checkout (using TortoiseSVN):

```
Error: Can't move 'C:\Users\Adam\Documents\svncheckout\.svn\tmp\svn-E48F31BD' to 
Error: 'C:\Users\Adam\Documents\svncheckout\.svn\pristine\f8\f8b8ac3ff36b5da836c377819e79f5a8a88df926.svn-base': 
Error: The system cannot find the file specified. 
Error: Additional errors: 
Error: Can't create directory 'C:\Users\Adam\Documents\svncheckout\.svn\pristine\f8': 
Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

I have tried doing an SVN cleanup, disabling anti-virus/firewalls, as well as copying over the specified .svn-base file from my other computer (windows seems to auto-delete it on creation).

I have also tried a different SVN Client (SmartSVN) and I get the same error. I've tried to do a checkout around 10 times and it almost always happens at the same time, but I've had one that went further before giving me that error. No clue why.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your remote directory, did you set the path for checkout at that time itself?
I did the same and when I added the file into repository browser and tried to check it out, it gave me the same error.

I created the remote directory afresh and left it there. Then I went to repository browser and added my file and did right click checkout. Here I provided the path for checkout and bingo!!!

Regards.
Sachin